# How do i create my own watch function similar to angular in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js

I am a big fan of angular and loves the two-way binding concept and the watch functionality.but my present firm is using Backbone Stack and i could not find a way to include Angular JS into Backbone Stack. (If there is a way . Well and good)

I want to do some UI manipulation based on value change of a simple variable.(Need not be a object).

And If possible i want to extend it a object 1 level deep like

```
 var watchObj = {
   variable1 : 1,
   variable2 : 2
 }
```

If any of the key-value pair change i want to do some UI manipulation(Depending on the  key ).

How can i achieve this with minimum possible javascript code.

Comment: What about Epoxy? Or `Backbone.ModelBinder` e.g., http://niki4810.github.io/blog/2013/03/02/new-post/?

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton , i will look in to it. But i want to implement this functionality myself in vanilla JS. there is a lot of restriction in adding new libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend including Angular into Backbone and if you use Backbone stack you should really go through the tutorial (http://backbonejs.org/). Maybe you will find that things could be done without two-way data binding concept (http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-why-backbone).

If you man by 'vanilla JS' no framework at all, then you should check Object.observe functionality (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) which not supported yet widely enough to use in production (http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-observe) - and thats why there are so many MVC frameworks with slightly different concepts but doing the same in the end:)

Comment: Thanks for this view of tackling the problem. But if it cant be put in production. It is as good as bad.

Comment: its currently removed from the ecmascript proposal